# How can i fetch all json file data - ionic angular

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I have this code and I can fetch data from (number) and (name) only, how can I fetch data from elements
I tried many ways, but I couldn't find a solution
Please help me

JSON

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "name": "ahmed",
        "elements": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "text": "text1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "text": "text2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "text": "text3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

TS File

```
  data: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    fetch('./assets/data/datajson.json').then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.data = json;
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-card mode="ios" *ngFor="let item of data; index as i">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: you need to export your JSON data from json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over inner key. in this case elements

```
       <ion-card mode="ios" *ngFor="let item of data; index as i">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
<ion-item *ngFor="let ele of item.elements">
      <ion-label>{{ ele.id}}-{{ele.text}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much
I'm trying now when I press the button to go to another page routerLink="/detils"
And transfer the data of the first person to the next page, but the problem is that all the data of the other people are printed, is there a way to distinguish each name with a unique identifier

Comment: As per stack overflow community guidelines we should not ask `How-to` questions. But if you try and face any issues or errors, feel free to ask new questions with your tried ways. All the best